# Android studio - alinear textos en RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

estoy teniendo un problema en un RecyclerView hecho con FirestoreRecyclerOptions donde estoy haciendo un pequeño chat. La idea es que el nombre del usuario salga alineado a la izquierda normalmente, pero si es un texto introducido por el mismo usuario que está accediendo, su nombre salga a la derecha.

Ésto me lo hace correctamente al inicio, pero se desalinea cuando hago scroll para arriba o para abajo.

Paso el onBindViewHolder ya que creo que el problema lo tengo ahí:

```
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Chat chat) {
        holder.mTxtUsuario.setText(chat.getUsuario());
        holder.mTxtMensaje.setText(chat.getMensaje());

        if (obtenerPerfil().getEmail().equals(chat.getEmail())) {
            holder.mTxtUsuario.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.mTxtUsuario.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END);
        } else {
            holder.mTxtUsuario.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0844C5"));
            holder.mTxtUsuario.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
        }
   }
```

Paso también el xml del elemento por si acaso:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtUsuario"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#0844C5"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMensaje"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/borde_layout_gris"/>
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Gracias :)

Al cargar el recycler:

[image: Imagen al cargar el recycler:]

Después de realizar scroll hacia arriba y abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: alguna imagen de lo que pasa preview. Aunque seria mejor que el alinamiento lo hagas con la vista en un contraintlayout. Es lo que hago a la hora de un chat. Una vista hija es la que se alineara.

Comment: Me ha funcionado como dices, con un ConstrantLayout y los TextViews, y sin cambiar el código del recycler. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @sergionuñezsanchez podrías marcar tu pregunta como resuelta o poner como lo solucionaste? Entre queriendo ayudar y analicé la situación y ahora leo el comentario de que ya esta solucionado. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paso respuesta de cómo lo he solucionado gracias a OsAndNoTi. La idea ha sido cambiar el LinearLayour por  ConstrantLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_margin="2dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtUsuario"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMensaje"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/borde_layout_gris"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUsuario" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```